# Receive multipart/form-data with Nestjs

Tags: typescript, nestjs, multipartform-data

I have a camera that posts events to my backend (nestjs) when something occurs. Using a TCP Server I have noticed that the content-type is multipart/form-data. Here is an event fired by the camera.

```
??Receive from 192.168.1.64 : 37100????POST /events HTTP/1.1
Content-Type: multipart/form-data; boundary=boundary
Host: 192.168.3.4:3000
Connection: close
Content-Length: 848686

--boundary
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="anpr.xml"; filename="anpr.xml"
Content-Type: text/xml
Content-Length: 2255

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<EventNotificationAlert version="2.0" xmlns="http://www.hikvision.com/ver20/XMLSchema">
<ipAddress>192.168.1.64</ipAddress>
<portNo>3000</portNo>
<protocol>HTTP</protocol>
<macAddress>24:28:fd:b8:80:4a</macAddress>
<channelID>1</channelID>
<dateTime>2022-01-06T15:54:36+08:00</dateTime>
<activePostCount>1</activePostCount>
<eventType>ANPR</eventType>
<eventState>active</eventState>
<eventDescription>ANPR</eventDescription>
<channelName>Camera 01</channelName>
<ANPR>
<country>0</country>
<licensePlate>unknown</licensePlate>
<line>1</line>
<direction>forward</direction>
<confidenceLevel>0</confidenceLevel>
<plateType>unknown</plateType>
<plateColor>unknown</plateColor>
<licenseBright>0</licenseBright>
<dangmark>unknown</dangmark>
<twoWheelVehicle>no</twoWheelVehicle>
<threeWheelVehicle>no</threeWheelVehicle>
<plateCharBelieve></plateCharBelieve>
<vehicleType>vehicle</vehicleType>
<detectDir>8</detectDir>
<detectType>0</detectType>
<alarmDataType>0</alarmDataType>
<vehicleInfo>
<index>726</index>
<colorDepth>2</colorDepth>
<color>black</color>
<speed>0</speed>
<length>0</length>
<vehicleLogoRecog>1788</vehicleLogoRecog>
<vehileSubLogoRecog>0</vehileSubLogoRecog>
<vehileModel>0</vehileModel>
</vehicleInfo>
<pictureInfoList>
<pictureInfo>
<fileName>vehiclePicture.jpg</fileName>
<type>vehiclePicture</type>
<dataType>0</dataType>
<picRecogMode>1</picRecogMode>
<absTime>20220106155436260</absTime>
<pId>2022010615543664300KLv83pW6rkPCV</pId>
</pictureInfo>
<pictureInfo>
<fileName>detectionPicture.jpg</fileName>
<type>detectionPicture</type>
<dataType>0</dataType>
<picRecogMode>1</picRecogMode>
<absTime>20220106155436260</absTime>
<plateRect>
<X>0</X>
<Y>0</Y>
<width>0</width>
<height>0</height>
</plateRect>
<pId>20220106155436644002O5GsQnhGBUYI</pId>
</pictureInfo>
</pictureInfoList>
<originalLicensePlate>unknown</originalLicensePlate>
<CRIndex>0</CRIndex>
<vehicleListName>otherList</vehicleListName>
</ANPR>
<UUID>2022010615543664300U2sWbBWlfOnL8gC9sl9oEcp7Gp1VImuvKFGGvuvp1vkh</UUID>
<picNum>2</picNum>
<monitoringSiteID></monitoringSiteID>
<isDataRetransmission>false</isDataRetransmission>
</EventNotificationAlert>

--boundary
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="vehiclePicture.jpg"; filename="2022010615543664300KLv83pW6rkPCV.jpg"
Content-Type: image/jpeg
Content-Length: 561449

(binary data)
???¡§¡è???¨C?6?ßZÃ)’)lÖ8Ã•#sl˜ëï@¿¢]ÊMÕ-ïæåŠÇ3?\?¨®?y?s?^?B?u¡§¡ã??|????&N3?¨²????u@>????¡À?n3@  Û08ÛÛåñ“œ÷
```

As you can see, there are two fields: anpr.xml and vehiclePicture.jpg

Here is the endpoint to receive events.

```
export const eventFileFilter = (req, file, callback) => {
  if (!file.originalname.match(/\.(jpg|jpeg|png|gif|xml|zip)$/)) {
    return callback(new Error('Invalid file!'), false);
  }
  callback(null, true);
};

export const editFileName = (req, file, callback) => {
  const name = file.originalname.split('.')[0];
  const fileExtName = extname(file.originalname);
  const timestamp = Date.now();
  callback(null, `${name}-${timestamp}${fileExtName}`);
};

//////// events.controller.ts

  @Post()
  @UseInterceptors(
    FileFieldsInterceptor(
      [
        { name: 'anpr.xml', maxCount: 1 },
        { name: 'licensePlatePicture.jpg', maxCount: 1 },
      ],
      {
        storage: diskStorage({
          destination: './upload',
          filename: editFileName,
        }),
        fileFilter: eventFileFilter,
      },
    ),
  )
  async create(
    @UploadedFiles()
    files: {
      eventData?: Express.Multer.File[];
      picture?: Express.Multer.File[];
    },
  ): Promise<any> {
    console.log(files['anpr.xml'][0], files['licensePlatePicture.jpg'][0]);
  }
```

Using Postman like this I received the events with no problem
[image]

Any ideas? Thanks!

Comment: So, when the camera sends the request, is the event just not seen, or is the data mishandled or something? It's not clear what the problem is

Comment: Yes, the data is mishandled because I can receive events in a flat tcp server, but not in nestjs backend.

Comment: If its an actual TCP event being sent and not an HTTP request (doesn't look to be the case) then you'd need your own TCP handler installed, right?